# turning caption into a link doesn't work in Lightbox 2.51

Tags: hyperlink, lightbox, caption

Turning a caption into a link doesn't work in Lightbox 2.51 downloaded from [here](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)
Here is the code:

```
<a href="images/examples/image-1.jpg" rel="lightbox" 
  title="&lt;a target='_self' href='http://www.google.com'&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;">
  <img src="images/examples/thumb-1.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

What should I do?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 11):

I found a solution for this problem in the `lightbox.js`.
You must edit the `if` case, adding the `else` condition that avoid always return `false` when you click in the `div` "lightbox" .

```
 $lightbox.hide().on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).attr('id') === 'lightbox') { 
        _this.end();
        return false;
    }
    else { // HERE
        return true; 
    }
  });
```

Comment: This method will probably work in most cases but I think it could have some unintentional side effects, because it will effect all clicks that bubble up to the lightbox. I've added a more limited intervention in my answer below, which will only register an event on links inside the caption.

Answer (score 3):

I found what I think is a better solution than those listed above using Lightbox 2 version 2.6. On line 252 of lightbox.js (unminified), you'll see this line which adds the caption:

```
this.$lightbox.find('.lb-caption').html(this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title).fadeIn('fast');
```

Once the caption is added, you can register the click event and force the browser to follow any link in the caption by adding onto the chain like this:

```
this.$lightbox.find('.lb-caption').html(this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title).fadeIn('fast').find('a').on('click', function() { location.href = $(this).attr('href') });
```

I've initiated a [pull request](https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/pull/194) with this change so you can follow the status and any further discussions there.

Answer (score 2):

Try using javascript in tag

onClick="window.location.href='http://www.google.com'"

Sample

```
    <a href="images/examples/image-1.jpg" rel="lightbox" 
  title="&lt;a target='_self' onClick=&quot;window.location.href=&#x27;http://www.google.com&#x27;&quot;   href='http://www.google.com'&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;">
 <img src="images/examples/thumb-1.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been unable to get any of the answers here to work for me. However, I have found that [Slimbox2](http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2) does work and is very straightforward to swap as it uses the same syntax.