# How do I add a link to a Title/Caption in LightBox 2 Gallery

Tags: lightbox2

I would like to add a link to a title/Caption on the last image in of a Lightbox 2 gallery to point to the next physical page of this particular gallery.

I tried the code below but it didn't work and only displayed the link code above the image in the page.

```
<td width="177" valign="top"><a href="images/galleries/bath/21.jpg" rel="lightbox[ed]" title="Click <a href="gallery-bathroom-2.html>HERE<a> to continue viewing Gallery"><img src="images/galleries/bath/thumbs/21t.jpg" alt="Remodel Bathroom" width="178" height="123" border="0" /></a></td>
```

If you go to http://revdesigndev.com/rc/gallery-bathroom-update.html and click on the last image in the gallery you will see the caption I would like to link from.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I can't claim credit for this one, but the answer is already on StackOverflow.  You need to edit the if statement as Zenpoy suggests.

[turning caption into a link doesn't work in Lightbox 2.51](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119879/turning-caption-into-a-link-doesnt-work-in-lightbox-2-51)