# how to add custom html in caption of lightbox2

Tags: jquery, lightbox2

I want to add custom html in lightbox2 caption code using different attributes. I want to add URL, Product name and product code.

This is my gallery.

http://psd2htmlexpert.com/work/cs-gallery/

I can just add simple text in caption.

Thanks in advance.
Here is an example of what i want.

http://temp.simpleidea.us/cs-gallery/gallery.html

Comment: It seems you need to edit the library's source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119879/turning-caption-into-a-link-doesnt-work-in-lightbox-2-51

Comment: yes you are right. but I don't have much knowledge to do this :( i try it but everything got messed.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of Googling and it seems that this has been added to the latest version of Lightbox 2. Here's [the issue on the project's homepage](https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/issues/164).

So, for you that means, update your Lightbox version, then you can do:

```
<a href="images/1.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="<a href='http://google.com'>Link to google</a>. More text.">
  <img class='item' src='images/thumbs/1.jpg' />
  <span class='caption'>
    <span class='icon fa fa-search'></span>
  </span>
</a>
```

Here's [a demo](http://hibbard.eu/blog/pages/lightbox-with-link.html)